# How to remove a subview (or all subviews of a view)

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uiview

I have a method in which I alloc and init an

```
UIView (`tabsClippedView = [[[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:tabsClippedFrame] autorelease];`).
```

This view has another view added to it

```
(`tabsView = [[[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:tabsFrame] autorelease];`).
```

Then I initiate a couple of buttons

```
(e.g. `UIButton* btn = [[[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:frame] autorelease];`)
```

and add them to the subview of the view.

Now from time to time, I need to delete all the buttons and assign them again. Is the best way to delete the entire view or simply the subview to which I added the buttons?

How would I need to do this (without memory leaking etc.)? **Would a simple**

```
self.tabsView = nil;
```

**suffice to delete the view and all of its subviews (i.e. the buttons)?**

Or would it better to delete the superview as well, to start entirely from scratch:

```
self.tabsClippedView = nil;
```

Comment: I found the answer to this in another stackoverflow question: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2156046/374873

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Since your UIView is autoreleased, you just need to remove it from the superview. For which there is the `removeFromSuperview` method.

So, you'd just want to call `[self.tabsView removeFromSuperview]`. As long as your property declaration is set to `retain` that's all you'll need.

Comment: Thanks... so what about the self.tabsView = nil; command -- would that be wrong or different from removeFromSuperview? Thanks for your help!

Comment: `self.tabsView = nil` won't remove it from the superView.

Comment: What s/he said - you don't need to set it to nil, because as long as you've set up your @property declaration correctly this will be taken care of when you reassign the property.

Answer (score 4):

Another solution: don't remove your `UIButtons` but re-use them. Don't know the exact use-case for you, but you may assign `tags` to your `UIButtons` and find them with `[UIView viewWithTag:]`.

```
UIButton* btn = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
btn.tag = 42; // some unique identifier for the button.. dont use 0 (zero)
[tabsView addSubview:btn];
[btn release];
```

later...

```
UIButton* btn = (UIButton*)[tabsView viewWithTag:42];
if(btn && [btn isKindOfClass:[UIButton class]]) {
    // do some stuff with btn
}
```

Besides: In my opinion you only should use `autorelease` when you've no other options. Here it's easy for you to release `btn` after adding it as subview.

Comment: Thanks, but I need to entirely remove some buttons, so I guess this won't work. Thanks for your thoughts, though.