# How do you call removeFromSuperview in RubyMotion?

Tags: rubymotion

I'm looking to implement this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5851205/how-to-remove-a-subview-or-all-subviews-of-a-view) in RubyMotion.

How would the following statement look like?

```
[self.tabsView removeFromSuperview]
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found it -

```
view.removeFromSuperview()
```