# Remove Subview from current window

Tags: ios

I have a View 'A'.I am Adding a view 'B' as A's subview.If i click on a button on the view 'B' then another View 'C' is added.When i Click on the View 'A' am trying to remove the View 'C'.How to Remove view 'C' from view 'A'?.Please Help

Comment: 1. SubClass Views  and pass their touches to their superviews when required. 2.Set UserInteractionDisabled of different views accordingly  3.Add and removeSubviews. 4. subview.hidden=YES  Subview.alpha=0,1. I think any one of the approach can help you

Comment: And Try to improve your question  with some code

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to remove a subview (or all subviews of a view)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5851205/how-to-remove-a-subview-or-all-subviews-of-a-view)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
[cView removeFromSuperview];
```

By tag remove subview like this

```
[[Aview viewWithTag:yourTag] removeFromSuperview];
```

Try this. i hope it will be helpful for you..

Comment: :the prob is i can't create an object of viewcontoller C in A.So What else can i Do?

Comment: How you create the CView. Where you create set the tag. Use that tag remove the View from your superView

Comment: @user2771338:I update my code as you want just use that. Then set the tag for your Cview while create that view

Answer (score 1):

just try this in viewA:

```
[viewC removeFromSuperview];
```

Note: You must have reference of viewC in viewA.

Answer (score 0):

In the method click of View A, you can remove View C with the help of this code:-

```
[viewC removeFromSuperview];
```

Hope this will help you out.

Comment: if this doesn't helps you out..please share some piece of code such that we can help you out.

Answer (score -1):

try this to hide a *subView*

```
    subView.hidden = YES;
```

in your buttonAction.