# How to refresh uiscrollview?

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, refresh

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Best way to refresh/reload UIScrollView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9217772/best-way-to-refresh-reload-uiscrollview)

I need to refresh a uiscrollview with page control 
I have tried with setneeddisplay with no success
So how to refresh a uiscrollview ?

Comment: Why you want to refresh scrollview? Usually scroll view will be refreshed everytime when subview is added/removed

Comment: I need to refresh it because it contains many uiimage from web server

Answer (score 0):

If you mean returning to the first image or to top by resetting, you may try:

```
[_scrollView scrollRectToVisible:CGRectMake(0, 0, _scrollView.frame.size.width, _scrollView.frame.size.height) animated:YES];
```