# Remove added viewControllers view using removeFromSuperview all at once

Tags: ios7, uiview, xcode5

I have added `viewcontrollers` in following fashion:

in first `viewController`:

```
[self.view addsubview:secondViewcontroller.view];
```

Then in second `viewController`:

```
[self.view addsubview:thirdViewcontroller.view];
```

Then in third `viewController`:

```
[self.view addsubview:fourthViewcontroller.view];
```

Now i am in `fouthViewcontroller` and want to go back to `firsiViewController` using `removeFromSuperview` method.

How can we achieve this? Is there any other way to do this. I don't want to use `UINavigationController`.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2156015/remove-all-subviews     try this

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code, it may work

```
NSArray * subviews = [self.view subviews];
    int cnt = [subviews count];
    for(int j=cnt-1; j >=0 ; --j )
    {
        UIView * sview = [subviews objectAtIndex:j];
        [sview removeFromSuperview];
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

In one row

```
[self.view.subviews makeObjectsPerformSelector:@selector(removeFromSuperview)];
```