# How to remove all subviews of a view in Swift?

Tags: macos, view, swift

I'm looking for a simple method to remove at once all subviews from a superview instead of removing them one by one.

```
//I'm trying something like this, but is not working
let theSubviews : Array = container_view.subviews
for (view : NSView) in theSubviews {
    view.removeFromSuperview(container_view)
}
```

What I am missing?

**UPDATE**

My app has a main `container_view`. I have to add different other views as subviews to `container_view` in order to provide a sort of navigation.

So, when clicking the button to "open" a particular page, I need to remove allsubviews and add the new one.

**UPDATE 2 - A working solution (OS X)**

I guess Apple fixed it.

Now it is more easy than ever, just call:

```
for view in containerView.subviews{
    view.removeFromSuperview()
}
```

Comment: I'd like to point out that @sulthan's answer, while buried with the rags, is the superior answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24312760/swift-how-will-i-remove-all-the-subviews-of-a-view/24314054#24314054

Comment: @ChristopherSwasey Swift 4 gives an error: Cannot assign to property: 'subviews' is a get-only property. :(

Comment: @WilliamT.Mallard how many times does it have to be repeated that this method and question is about MacOS and not iOS?

Answer (score 413, accepted):

EDIT: (thanks Jeremiah / Rollo)

By far the best way to do this in Swift for iOS is:

```
view.subviews.forEach({ $0.removeFromSuperview() }) // this gets things done
view.subviews.map({ $0.removeFromSuperview() }) // this returns modified array
```

^^ These features are fun!

```
let funTimes = ["Awesome","Crazy","WTF"]
extension String { 
    func readIt() {
        print(self)
    }
}

funTimes.forEach({ $0.readIt() })
```

//// END EDIT

Just do this:

```
for view in self.view.subviews {
    view.removeFromSuperview()
}
```

Or if you are looking for a specific class

```
for view:CustomViewClass! in self.view.subviews {
        if view.isKindOfClass(CustomViewClass) {
            view.doClassThing()
        }
    }
```

Comment: In Xcode 7.0 beta 6 this generates a warning: "result of call to 'map' is unused". I hope this gets fixed in the final version.

Comment: I noticed that as well! I'll update the post once Xcode comes out of beta and the problem still persists.

Comment: The warning, `result of call to 'map' is unused `, is not an error. `Array.map` in most languages will return the modified array. The equivalent method which doesn't return an array, would be `view.subviews.forEach`.

Comment: ```for view:CustomViewClass! in self.view.subviews where view.isKindOfClass(CustomViewClass) {
    view.doClassThing()
    }```

Comment: I would argue that this is"By far the best way to do this in Swift" , see http://stackoverflow.com/a/24314054/1974224

Comment: @Cristik view.subviews is now a read-only property in Swift so the suggestion wouldn't work now.

Comment: The [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSView_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/NSView/subviews) kinda says another thing.

Comment: @Bseaborn I think you're confusing `NSView` and `UIView`,  for `UIView` indeed, the `subviews` property is readonly.

Comment: @Cristik I stand corrected! Thanks for pointing that out. Indeed I was confusing the two. I'll update my answer.

Answer (score 46):

For iOS/Swift, to get rid of all subviews I use:

```
for v in view.subviews{
   v.removeFromSuperview()
}
```

to get rid of all subviews of a particular class (like UILabel) I use:

```
for v in view.subviews{
   if v is UILabel{
      v.removeFromSuperview()
   }
}
```

Answer (score 40):

The code can be written simpler as following.

```
view.subviews.forEach { $0.removeFromSuperview() }
```

Answer (score 24):

This should be the simplest solution.

```
let container_view: NSView = ...
container_view.subviews = []
```

(see [Remove all subviews?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2156015/remove-all-subviews) for other methods)

---

Note this is a **MacOS** question and this answer works only for **MacOS**. It does not work on iOS.

Comment: This is definitely the simplest way... removeFromSuperview is automatically called for each view that is no longer in the subviews array.

Comment: @datayeah They are not but there is a big difference between `NSView` (OS X) and `UIView` (iOS).

Comment: @Sulthan you're right. I came here for the Swift answer for UIView and did'nt read your whole code snippet ;)

Comment: I'm more inclined to create an extension to implement `removeAllSubviews()` on `UIView`. Easier to remember.

Comment: Swift 4 gives an error: Cannot assign to property: 'subviews' is a get-only property. :(

Comment: @WilliamT.Mallard This was originally an OS X question and this is OS X answer.

Comment: @AmrAngry Again, I repeat, this was always a Mac OS question, for `NSView`, not iOS and `UIView`. Only people don't care to read the question and tags therefore it got filled with iOS answers.

Answer (score 24):

## Swift 5

I create 2 different methods to remove subview. And it's much easier to use if we put them in `extension`

```
extension UIView {
    /// Remove all subview
    func removeAllSubviews() {
        subviews.forEach { $0.removeFromSuperview() }
    }

    /// Remove all subview with specific type
    func removeAllSubviews<T: UIView>(type: T.Type) {
        subviews
            .filter { $0.isMember(of: type) }
            .forEach { $0.removeFromSuperview() }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 14):

Try this:

```
for view in container_view.subviews {
    view.removeFromSuperview()
}
```

Answer (score 11):

I don't know if you managed to resolve this but I have recently experienced a similar problem where the For loop left one view each time. I found this was because the self.subviews was mutated (maybe) when the removeFromSuperview() was called.

To fix this I did:

```
let subViews: Array = self.subviews.copy()
for (var subview: NSView!) in subViews
{
    subview.removeFromSuperview()
}
```

By doing .copy(), I could perform the removal of each subview while mutating the self.subviews array. This is because the copied array (subViews) contains all of the references to the objects and is not mutated.

EDIT: In your case I think you would use:

```
let theSubviews: Array = container_view.subviews.copy()
for (var view: NSView!) in theSubviews
{
    view.removeFromSuperview()
}
```

Comment: Hello, try the following although there is probably a much more elegant way to do this:

`let subViewsArray: Array = (parentView.subviews as NSArray).copy() as Array<NSView>`

Answer (score 11):

Extension for remove all subviews, it is quickly removed.

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

extension UIView {
    /// Remove allSubView in view
    func removeAllSubViews() {
        self.subviews.forEach({ $0.removeFromSuperview() })
    }

}
```

Comment: why map? foreach maybe ? subviews.forEach { $0.removeFromSuperview() }

Comment: Yes you right @Aleksandr i think when i was writing this, i did not have take my coffee

Answer (score 8):

Try this:

```
var subViews = parentView.subviews as Array<UIView>

      for someView in subViews
      {
          someView.removeFromSuperview()
      }
```

**UPDATE**: If you are feeling adventurous then you can make an extension on the UIView as shown below:

```
extension UIView
{
    func removeAllSubViews()
    {
       for subView :AnyObject in self.subviews
       {
            subView.removeFromSuperview()
       }
    }

}
```

And call it like this:

```
parentView.removeAllSubViews()
```

Comment: 2 little things: I'm working on osx, therefore it would be <NSView> right ? Then, I am getting "fatal error: Array index out of range" :/

Comment: Yes, I think on OSX it is NSView. Where do you get the fatal error?

Comment: Are you sure that your parent view has child elements?

Comment: Yep ! If i make a println(parentView.subviews) i get 1

Comment: That is strange! Usually out of range means that you are accessing an index which does not exist and usually I believe it is caused by using a for loop with indexes like i++.

Answer (score 7):

In xcodebeta6 this worked out.

```
    var subViews = self.parentView.subviews
    for subview in subViews as [UIView]   {
        subview.removeFromSuperview()
    }
```

Comment: That is iOS. I need a solution for OS X

Comment: Great Solution for IOS +1

Answer (score 5):

**Swift 3**

If you add a tag to your view you can remove a specific view.

```
for v in (view?.subviews)!
{
    if v.tag == 321
    {
         v.removeFromSuperview()
    }
 }
```

Comment: why not `view.subviews.filter({$0.tag != 321}).forEach({$0.removeFromSuperview()})`?

Answer (score 4):

I wrote this extension:

```
extension UIView {
    func lf_removeAllSubviews() {
        for view in self.subviews {
            view.removeFromSuperview()
        }
    }
}
```

So that you can use self.view.lf_removeAllSubviews in a UIViewController. I'll put this in the swift version of my https://github.com/superarts/LFramework later, when I have more experience in swift (1 day exp so far, and yes, for API I gave up underscore).

Answer (score 3):

Your syntax is slightly off. Make sure you cast explicitly.

```
 let theSubviews : Array<NSView> = container_view.subviews as Array<NSView>
 for view in theSubviews {
     view.removeFromSuperview()
 }
```

Comment: @David Yes it will, I tried to keep it as close to FoxNos's initial code as possible.

Answer (score 3):

you have to try this

```
func clearAllScrollSubView ()
{
    let theSubviews = itemsScrollView.subviews

    for (var view) in theSubviews
    {

        if view is UIView
        {
            view.removeFromSuperview()
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: That is UI not NS. Here we're talking about OS X. If that works even with it by replacing UI with NS, my bad, you were right :)

Answer (score 2):

Try this out , I tested this :

```
  let theSubviews = container_view.subviews
  for subview in theSubviews {
      subview.removeFromSuperview()
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

For removing just subviews of a specific class - this was the only Swift code that worked for me in Xcode6.1.1.
Assuming the only subviews you want to remove are of type **UIButton**...

```
for subView in nameofmysuperview.subviews {
    if subView.isKindOfClass(UIButton) {
        subView.removeFromSuperview()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

For Swift 3

I did as following because just removing from superview did not erase the buttons from array.

```
    for k in 0..<buttons.count {

      buttons[k].removeFromSuperview()

    }


    buttons.removeAll()
```

Answer (score 2):

For `Swift 4.+`

```
extension UIView {
     public func removeAllSubViews() {
          self.subviews.forEach({ $0.removeFromSuperview() })

}
```

i hope this is use full for you.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a one-liner you've been looking for:

```
view.subviews.filter({$0.tag == 321}).forEach({$0.removeFromSuperview()})
```

Don't forget to Tag your view (`someView.tag = 321`) before you remove it with this code.

Answer (score 1):

### One-liner:

```
while view.subviews.count > 0  { (view.subviews[0] as? NSView)?.removeFromSuperview() }
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's another approach that allows you call the operation on any collection of `UIView` instances (or `UIView` subclasses). This makes it easy to insert things like `filter` after `.subviews` so you can be more selective, or to call this on other collections of `UIView`s.

```
extension Array where Element: UIView {
  func removeEachFromSuperview() {
    forEach {
      $0.removeFromSuperview()
    }
  }
}
```

Example usage:

```
myView.subviews.removeEachFromSuperview()

// or, for example:

myView.subivews.filter { $0 is UIImageView }.removeEachFromSuperview()
```

Alternatively you can accomplish the same thing with a `UIView` extension (though this can't be called on some arbitrary array of `UIView` instances):

```
extension UIView {
    func removeSubviews(predicate: ((UIView) -> Bool)? = nil) 
        subviews.filter(
            predicate ?? { _ in true }
        ).forEach {
            $0.removeFromSuperview()
        }
    }
}
```

Example usage:

```
myView.removeSubviews()
myView.removeSubviews { $0 is UIImageView }
```

Answer (score -3):

did you try something like

```
for o : AnyObject in self.subviews {
     if let v = o as? NSView {
         v.removeFromSuperview()
     }
}
```