# How to remove only user-added subviews from my UIView

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, subviews

I'm trying to remove all the subviews that I've added to my view, so I've implemented a loop to iterate over the subviews with the following:

```
for subview in view.subviews {
    println(subview)
    //subview.removeFromSuperview()
}
```

I tested this by adding a UILabel to my view and then ran this code. The output contained my UILabel but also a _UILayoutGuide. So, my question is how can I determine if a subview is one that I added or one that the system added?

Comment: What if you specify the subview type like in this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/25067739/2274694 ?

Comment: @LyndseyScott I'm not sure how that will help me

Comment: Either way, are the views you're removing specific types, i.e. UIViews, UILabels, etc.? Because you can limit the subview removal by class... I can type up an answer for you.

Comment: Instead of working in `view`, you could add your own subview and place your labels there.  Then you can safely remove all the subviews of that view.

Comment: Actually, I ended up suggesting something a little more thorough. Check out my updated answer.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you just want to prevent the loop from removing the `_UILayoutGuide` (which is of class `UILayoutSupport`), try this:

```
for subview in self.view.subviews {
    if !(subview is UILayoutSupport) {
        print(subview)
        subview.removeFromSuperview()
     }
}
```

And generally speaking, if you'd like to prevent the removal of views other than the `_UILayoutGuide` and if you know the specific types of subviews you'd like to remove from your UIView, you can limit the subviews you remove to those types, ex:

```
for subview in view.subviews {
    if subview is ULabel {
        println(subview)
        subview.removeFromSuperview()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 11):

One option is to give all the views you add a specific tag. Then only remove them if they have that tag.

```
userCreatedView.tag = 100;
```

...

```
for subview in view.subviews {
    if (subview.tag == 100) {
        subview.removeFromSuperview()
    }
}
```

You could also keep an Array of all the subviews that the user has added then check to see if that subview is in your userAddedViewsArray

Or you could create a subclass of UIView for your user added views and then only remove the subviews that are that class

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately, I'm already using the tag property for something else.

Comment: Just added in a couple of other options. There are many ways to do this, and they're all pretty easy.

Comment: I was hoping to avoid adding extra code each time I add a new subview. Thanks for the good suggestions, though.

Comment: tag property saved me, Thanks

Answer (score 1):

i solve problem like this way....
first i added sub view

- **[self.view addSubview:genderPicker];**

then remove only that subview from the view

- **[genderPicker removeFromSuperview];**

Answer (score 0):

*indicator on off by string input fun*
*swift 2.2 and above*

```
func activityonoff(viewcontroler:UIViewController,string:String){
let container: UIView = UIView()
let loadingView: UIView = UIView()
if string == "on"{
container.frame = viewcontroler.view.frame
container.center = viewcontroler.view.center
container.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
container.alpha = 1
container.tag = 1

loadingView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 80, 80)
loadingView.center = container.center
loadingView.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 4/255, green: 68/255, blue: 68/255, alpha: 0.7)
loadingView.clipsToBounds = true
loadingView.layer.cornerRadius = 10

let actInd: UIActivityIndicatorView = UIActivityIndicatorView()
actInd.frame = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 40.0, 40.0);
actInd.activityIndicatorViewStyle = UIActivityIndicatorViewStyle.WhiteLarge
actInd.center = CGPointMake(loadingView.frame.size.width / 2,loadingView.frame.size.height / 2);
loadingView.addSubview(actInd)
container.addSubview(loadingView)
viewcontroler.view.addSubview(container)
actInd.startAnimating()
}
else{
    for v in viewcontroler.view.subviews{
        if v.tag == 1{
            v.removeFromSuperview()
        }
    }

}
```

}