# Dismissing embedded UITabbbar/storyboard in swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, storyboard, tabbarcontroller

I am trying to work with a social network framework (CometChat) which is either embedding a Storyboard or Tabbar controller on my UIApplication Window. Now i need a way to dismiss the embedded view when i am done interacting with it. I added a button to the window to call below method to dismiss the embedded

```
func dismiss() {
 let rootvc = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.rootViewController
    for v in (rootvc?.view.subviews)! {
        v.isHidden = true
    }
}
```

Every view behind the embedded view seems to disappear, but not the embedded view.[Screenshot of calling above method](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cu4Tp.png)

Tried looping through all windows and hiding views in windows, still no luck

```
let windows = UIApplication.shared.windows
    for window in windows {
        window.rootViewController?.view.isHidden = true
    }
```

Please Help, i have been on this for about 4 days now.. Thanks in advance.

Comment: if you wan to remove all subview then you can try this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24312760/how-to-remove-all-subviews-of-a-view-in-swift?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa

Comment: Tried the accepted answer, still no luck

Answer (score 0):

Since you are presenting Embedded ViewController you need to use popviewcontroller and then dismiss it. Kindly refer the below code:

```
navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)

dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
```

This should resolve the issue faced by you and you will be able to dismiss the EmbeddedViewController in your App.

Comment: You can also download the latest version of our SDK; we have added a close button option.